# visual c++ image filepath into xml

Tags: c++, xml

I need help with writing a XML file that includes the filepath of an image. 
In Visual C++, I'm using the saveFileDialog to save an XML. But before that I use an openImageDialog to open an image. I know that if I use: openImageDialog->FileName it gives the path of the image. I want to put this in the XML.
This is what I've tried:

```
String^ imgPath = (openImageDialog->FileName);
writer->WriteStartElement("Image");
writer->WriteElementString(openImageDialog->FileName);
```

But I get an error:
error C2661: 'System::Xml::XmlWriter::WriteElementString' : no overloaded function takes 1 arguments

I am using XMLTextWriter
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aex0e7zs.aspx), you need to specify element name and it's textual value for WriteElementString. For your case, you need to use

```
writer->WriteStartElement("Image")
writer->WriteString(openImageDialog->FileName);
writer->WriteEndElement();
```

OR

```
writer->WriteElementString("Image", openImageDialog->FileName);
```